# Best way to access jQuery version of DOM element from inside click event?

Tags: jquery

A common construction is this:

```
$('#someSelector').on('click', function(){
    $(this).doSomething();
    $(this).doSomethingElse();
});
```

The reason being that `this` refers to the native DOM  element, and if we want to use jQuery methods on it inside of the event handler, we need to re-wrap it. Of course I could create a var `$this = $(this);` to save myself having to repeatedly reconstruct it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Is there any way to access the element AS a jQuery object from inside a jQuery event handler?

Comment: No there is not a better way. But you can chain.

Comment: Even `$(event.target)` would need to be constantly reconstructed depending on the closure you're in.

Comment: `event.target !== this` in most cases. But that's not your main point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can store a reference to the element *outside the event handler* before attaching an event handler to it.

```
var $element = $('#someSelector');

$element.on('click', function () {
    $element.doSomething();
    $element.doSomethingElse();
});
```

(2) And as you mentioned you could store a reference inside the event handler.

```
$('#someSelector').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.doSomething();
    $this.doSomethingElse();
});
```

(3) Or if you're feeling crazy you can have a self invoked function inside the event handler that passes in `$this` as an argument.

```
$('#someSelector').on('click', function () {
    (function ($this) {
        $this.doSomething();
        $this.doSomethingElse();
    })($(this));
});
```

(4) Or you can even have a self invoked function called with the context of `$(this)` so that `this === $(this)`

```
$('#someSelector').on('click', function () {
    (function () {
        this.doSomething();
        this.doSomethingElse();
    }).call($(this));
});
```

(5) Or you can create an event handler with the context that you want using `Function.prototype.bind` or `$.proxy`

```
var $element = $('#someSelector');

$element.on('click', function () {
    this.doSomething();
    this.doSomethingElse();
}.bind($element));
```

You have some options...